# Can I refuse inserts/updates with timestamps without time-zone in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

I use exclusively timestamps *with* time-zone in PostgreSQL, but I just noticed something slightly worrying: If a client inserts/updates a record with a naïve time-stamp, PostgreSQL falls back to a default time-zone which is either given by an environment variable, localtime or a session-setting.

This might not always be correct.

Is it possible to configure PostgreSQL in a way that it will raise an error if it sees a value without time-zone?

Comment: PostgreSQL usually sees a string in the SQL statement that it interprets as a timestamp. Or are you using prepared statements?

Comment: In this case the data comes from a Python client. So as far as I can tell, PG will see it as a string as you say.

Comment: Then I don't think there is a lot you can do. You could set `timezone` to a good value, but the client can override it if it wants.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is feasible in your case, but you could use functions for inserting data. Use a `text` parameter for the timestamp and throw an error if the string doesn't contain a `+` or `-`.